# Mostrar vista de AngularJS desde arriba (scroll inicial)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quiero que cada vez que se acceda a determinada ruta en una aplicación Angular, la vista aparezca desde arriba, es decir con el scroll inicial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agregando `$anchorScroll()` e inyectandolo al controlador de tu vista Angular, te ubicara siempre la vista al inicio del HTML

```
.controller('viewController', ['$anchorScroll', function ($anchorScroll){
    $anchorScroll();        
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando ng-view solo tienes que usar autoscroll:

```
<div ng-view autoscroll><div>
```

Así no tienes que inyectar ningún servicio en los controladores.

Ejemplo en [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0m0RGLTSMv3YhR8q8M13/)